Proof of lemma 7.24 in High-Dimensional Statistics: A Non-Asymptotic Viewpoint
The lemma is a part of the proof of Theorem 7.16.
Theorem 7.16 states that(let $\rho^2(\Sigma)$ be the maximal diagonal entry of $\Sigma$)
Let $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}$ with each row $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^d$ being i.i.d from $N(0, \Sigma)$. Then there are universal constants $c_1 < 1 <c_2$ such that
$$\frac{\lVert X \theta\rVert_2^2}{n} \geq c_1 \lVert \sqrt{\Sigma}\theta\rVert_2^2 - c_2 \rho^2(\Sigma) \frac{\log d}{n} \lVert \theta \rVert_1^2$$
for all $\theta \in \mathbb{R}^d$, with probability at least $1-\frac{e^{-n/32}}{1-e^{-n/32}}$
We define  $g(t) = 2 \rho(\Sigma) \sqrt{\frac{\log d}{n}} t$ and we let $\mathcal{E} = \{ X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d} \colon \inf_{\theta \in \Theta} \frac{\lVert X \theta \rVert_2}{\sqrt{n}} + 2 g(\lVert \theta \rVert_1) \leq \frac{1}{4} \}$, where $\Theta = \{\theta \in \mathbb{R}^d \colon \lVert \sqrt{\Sigma} \theta \rVert_2 = 1 \}$.
We wish to put an upper bound on $P(\mathcal{E})$.
For a pair of $(r_l, r_i)$, $0 \leq r_l < r_u$, define
$K(r_l, r_u) = \{ \theta \in \Theta \colon g(\lVert \theta \rVert_1) \in [r_l, r_u] \}$ and $A(r_l, r_u) = \{X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d} \colon \inf_{\theta \in K(r_l, r_u)} \frac{\lVert X \theta \rVert_2}{\sqrt{n}} \leq \frac{1}{2}-2r_u \}$.
The lemma then states that
For any pair $0 \leq r_l < r_u$, we have $P(A(r_l, r_u)) \leq e^{\frac{-n}{32}} e^{\frac{-n}{2} r_u^2}$. Moreover, for $\mu = \frac{1}{4}$, $\mathcal{E} \subseteq A(0, \mu) \cup  (\cup_{l = 1}^\infty A(2^{l-1}\mu, 2^l \mu))$
Let $X \in \mathcal{E}$. Let $\theta$ be such that $\frac{\lVert X \theta \rVert_2}{\sqrt{n}} + 2g(\lVert \theta \rVert_1) \leq \frac{1}{4}$. The book then says that for $l = 1, 2, \ldots, $, if $\theta \in K(2^{l-1}\mu, 2^l \mu)$.
$\frac{\lVert X \theta \rVert_2}{\sqrt{n}} \leq \frac{1}{4}-2g(\lVert \theta \rVert_1) \leq \frac{1}{2} - 2(2^{l-1} \mu) = \frac{1}{2}-2^l \mu$.
But for $l =2$, $\frac{1}{2} - 2^l \mu = -\frac{1}{2}$, with $\frac{\lVert X \theta \rVert_2}{\sqrt{n}}\geq 0$. That doesn't make sense to me. What am I missing here?
Thank you.




